# event targeting with conditional style

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I'm trying to make an onClick function that makes a property in the component state turns to "true" when I click on a specific a tag

here is the state

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selected: false
      }
  }
```

Here is a the function, I'm just turning selected from false to true

```
  targetValue = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({selected: true});
  }




<div className="choose">
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
              <a href="#" onClick={this.targetValue} className={(this.state.selected ? "choosen" : "")}></a>
            </div>
```

The problem here is that when I click on one "a" tag, the styles gets applied on every "a" tag. I want it to just be applied to the clicked on "a" tag. Do I have to make a separate component for each "a" tag or is there a more proper way for applying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9l995oj90p

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: 0
    };
  }
  targetValue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selected: id });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selected);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a
          href="#"
          id={1}
          onClick={this.targetValue}
          className={this.state.selected === "1" ? "choosen" : ""}
        >
          Joj
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          id={2}
          onClick={this.targetValue}
          className={this.state.selected === "2" ? "choosen" : ""}
        >
          Joj
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          id={3}
          onClick={this.targetValue}
          className={this.state.selected === "3" ? "choosen" : ""}
        >
          Joj
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          id={4}
          onClick={this.targetValue}
          className={this.state.selected === "4" ? "choosen" : ""}
        >
          Joj
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: it gives me this error, I tried exactly what you wrote TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Sorry. I have changed my response.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem is about selecting a value, so here is what I would do:

1. Create a list of values (each value will be associated to your `a`  tag) and give each of them an ID (it can be a very simple number, like 0, 1, 2, ...
2. Modify the `targetValue` so that when you click on the `a` tag, you modify the `selectedItem` to the ID of the link you just clicked.
3. You add the `choosen` className to your link if the `selectedItem` correspond to the ID

---